# XSLT - find position() when inside a nested for-each

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach, position, xslt-2.0

I'm using XSLT to perform a transformation on some fairly complex XML. In order to achieve the output I need to, I've had to create a nested for loop something like the following:

*Source XML*

```
<root>
  <element1>
    <child>
      <aaa></aaa>
      <bbb></bbb>
    </child>
  </element1>
  <element2/>
  <element3/>
  <element3/>
  <element3/>
</root>
```

*XSLT*

```
<xsl:for-each select="element3">
  <!-- Do some stuff -->

  <xsl:for-each select="../element1/child/*">
    <!-- Do some more stuff -->
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

**Problem**

What I'm trying to do here is whilst in my nested loop (on `../element1/child/*`) - I'd like to find out:

1. The position of the element I'm currently looping - if, for example, I was currently focused on `<bbb>` then this position (I think) would be '1'
2. The position of the parent loop (on `element3`) - so if, for example, I was on the third instance of `<element3>` and then looping through `../element1/child/*` and was focused on `<aaa>` - the two values I would be after would be '2' and '0'.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to assign these values to a variable. I've tried using the `position()` notation like below but this doesn't seem to be working.

```
<xsl:for-each select="../element1/child/*">
  <xsl:variable name="postion_current_loop" select="position()"/>
  <xsl:variable name="postion_parent_loop" select="??????"/>
  <!-- Do some more stuff -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

If anyone has any ideas on how I could achieve this that would be greatly appreciated! I'm using XSLT 2.0, but am open to solutions using XSLT 1.0 if need be. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason that you are using `for-each` instead of separate templates. I can see at least one decent solution if you are using templates properly.

Comment: I'm currently only using a single template - I'm open to a solution that uses multiple as I'm yet to figure out how to achieve this. I'm fairly new to XSLT so haven't fully grasped the concept of multiple templates yet.

Comment: OK. This sort of thing is much easier with multiple templates (XSLT in general is - it's worth getting a good understanding of the concept).

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely explore that! For now, the answer provided by @michael.hor257k has provided me with a starting point for a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should try modifying your input to:

```
<root>
  <element1>
    <child>
      <aaa>1a</aaa>
      <bbb>2a</bbb>
    </child>
  </element1>
  <element2/>
  <element3>3a</element3>
  <element3>3b</element3>
  <element3>3c</element3>
</root>
```

then see what you get with:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <test>
        <xsl:for-each select="root/element3">
        <xsl:variable name="parent-position" select="position()" />
        <xsl:variable name="parent-value" select="." />
            <xsl:for-each select="../element1/child/*">
                <item value="{.}" parent-value="{$parent-value}" parent-position="{$parent-position}" position="{position()}"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>    
    </test>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added some id attributes to your input so you can see which node is getting processed where so my input looked like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <element1 id="e1-1">
        <child>
            <aaa id="e1-a"></aaa>
            <bbb id="e1-b"></bbb>
        </child>
    </element1>
    <element2 id="e2-1"/>
    <element3 id="e3-1"/>
    <element3 id="e3-2"/>
    <element3 id="e3-3"/>
</root>
```

This stylesheet does what I think you are trying to do - it processes each `element3` and processes all the `../element1/child/*` nodes for each `element3`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <tests>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="element3"/>
        </tests>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="element3">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../element1/child/*">
            <xsl:with-param name="parent-pos" select="position() - 1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="parent-id" select="@id"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="element1/child/*">
        <xsl:param name="parent-pos"/>
        <xsl:param name="parent-id"/>
        <xsl:variable name="current-pos" select="position()"/>

        <test parent-id="{$parent-id}" current-id="{@id}" parent-pos="{$parent-pos}" current-pos="{$current-pos}"/>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is:

```
<tests>
   <test parent-id="e3-1" current-id="e1-a" parent-pos="0" current-pos="1"/>
   <test parent-id="e3-1" current-id="e1-b" parent-pos="0" current-pos="2"/>
   <test parent-id="e3-2" current-id="e1-a" parent-pos="1" current-pos="1"/>
   <test parent-id="e3-2" current-id="e1-b" parent-pos="1" current-pos="2"/>
   <test parent-id="e3-3" current-id="e1-a" parent-pos="2" current-pos="1"/>
   <test parent-id="e3-3" current-id="e1-b" parent-pos="2" current-pos="2"/>
</tests>
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can internally rebuild the nodes with added @position attribute and just loop over the rebuild tree. For this exsl:node-set (or other proprietary derivates) is needed.

Taking your original source.xml (unchanged!) and this XSLT script:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">

<xsl:variable name="CopiedTree">
  <xsl:call-template name="copy-with-position"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($CopiedTree)//element3">
  <xsl:element name="E3">
    <xsl:comment>Do some stuff</xsl:comment>
    <xsl:variable name="E3pos" select="@position()" />

    <xsl:for-each select="../element1/child/*">
      <xsl:element name="E1C">
        <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="name()" /></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="positions"><xsl:value-of select="concat($E3pos, ' - ', @position)" /></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:comment>Do some more stuff</xsl:comment>
      </xsl:element>
      
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>





    
<xsl:template name="copy-with-position">

  <xsl:element name="{name()}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="(@*)" />
    <xsl:attribute name="position"><xsl:value-of select="position()" /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:for-each select="./*">
      <xsl:call-template name="copy-with-position">
        <xsl:with-param name="position" select="position()" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:element>

</xsl:template>
```

output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<E3>
  <!--Do some stuff-->
  <E1C name="aaa" positions="3 - 1">
    <!--Do some more stuff-->
  </E1C>
  <E1C name="bbb" positions="3 - 2">
    <!--Do some more stuff-->
  </E1C>
</E3>
<E3>
  <!--Do some stuff-->
  <E1C name="aaa" positions="4 - 1">
    <!--Do some more stuff-->
  </E1C>
  <E1C name="bbb" positions="4 - 2">
    <!--Do some more stuff-->
  </E1C>
</E3>
<E3>
  <!--Do some stuff-->
  <E1C name="aaa" positions="5 - 1">
    <!--Do some more stuff-->
  </E1C>
  <E1C name="bbb" positions="5 - 2">
    <!--Do some more stuff-->
  </E1C>
</E3>
```